# `void *` to other pointer

Tags: c, void-pointers

If I pass a `void *vptr` to a function which takes a `other_type *ptr` as its arg, will `vptr` be converted automatically to `other_type *`? Here is the code,

```
typedef struct A {
    //...
}A;

void bar(A *a)
{
    //do something with a
}

int main()
{
    A a = {..};
    void *vp = &a;
    bar(vp);  //will vp be converted to A*?
}
```

Is my code safe or correct?

Comment: what result do you get? error, warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `void*` is implicitly convertible to any pointer type, and any pointer type is implicitly convertible to `void*`. This is why you do not need to (and should not) cast the return value of `malloc`, for example.

Comment: So, my code is just right? I mean I don't have to do anything like `(void *)` on other_type, nor do I have to do `(other_type *)` on `void *`.

Comment: @Alcott that is correct, your code is both safe and correct. You can convert back and forth between any type and `void*` without casts in C (but not in C++).

Comment: @Alcott the designer of C++ just decided not to allow that, so you have to explicitly cast `void*` to other pointer types in C++.

Comment: Which was a really brain-damaged decision, since the entire point of `void *` is that it implicitly casts. Otherwise it's a useless duplicate of `char *`.

Comment: So I should use `reinterpret_cast` to do the job, right? C allows implicit cast between `void *` and other types, but C++ is not designed that way, right?

Comment: @Alcott he's just meaning that it was a dumb decision to design C++ like that because without the implicit casting, it works exactly like `char*` and is pointless.

Comment: The only reason for having `void *` in C is that it has convenient implicit-conversion properties that allow you to avoid littering your code with casts, which in turn can hide nasty bugs. (In the wild, I'd estimate 50-80% of casts are "warning fixes" that mask a real bug rather than fixing anything.) Other than that property and the fact that you're not allowed to do arithmetic on it, `void *` is the same as `char *`. They're even guaranteed to have the same representation, and all pointers are guaranteed to survive the round trip to `char *` and back.

Comment: @R.., +1 for the `round trip`, :-)

Comment: @R..: In C++, implicit casts from `T*` to `void*` are still legal, just not in the other direction, so it's not the same as `char*`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will work. You can pass a void * to something expecting a struct A *. C is only weakly typed in this regard.